# angular js resize operation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.hideConfig();
    });
});
```

> ReferenceError: $window is not defined
>       at new  (tpsGridList.js:590)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4182)
>       at $get.extend.instance (angular.js:8445)

Showing error while performing resizing event.
Can anyone help to generate the resize event in angular js?

Comment: Can you please show the whole directive / controller? Seems like you didn't inject `$window`.

Answer (score 1):

`$window` is a service. If you want to apply this directive to `window` just use

```
.directive('window', ...)
```

Comment: which method usable for resize listener event in angular.js